# i want add style on button without css file

Tags: reactjs

here is my js file
and i want to style on the pdfbtn
how can i do?
i want change the button's location
and i also don't want to make a css file
bacause i want to change style only button...

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactToPrint from 'react-to-print';

import Portfolio from './Portfolio';
 
class PdfComponent extends React.Component {
     
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <ReactToPrint
            content={() => this.componentRef}
            trigger={() => <button className="pdfbtn btn btn-primary">PDF로 저장</button>}
          />
          <Portfolio ref={(response) => (this.componentRef = response)} />
        </div>
      );
    }
 
}

export default PdfComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a style in React by passing an object into the style attribute:

```
<div>
  <ReactToPrint
    content={() => this.componentRef}
    trigger={() => <button className="pdfbtn btn btn-primary" style={{leftMargin:"20px"}}>PDF로 저장</button>}
  />
  <Portfolio ref={(response) => (this.componentRef = response)} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style it by adding inline `style` prop to the element:

```
<button style={{ padding: '10px' }} className="pdfbtn btn btn-primary">PDF로 저장</button>
```

or

```
const styles = { button : { padding : '10px' } };

<button style={ styles.button } className="pdfbtn btn btn-primary">PDF로 저장</button>
```

More details [here](https://medium.com/technofunnel/4-ways-to-add-styles-to-react-component-37c2a2034e3e)